# Intellij: how to directly open relevant file when clicking on class icon?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

[image]

My file structure looks like the above picture.

Now, when I click on `Environment`,  it shows me all of the methods on the sidebar, rather than opening up the file `Environment.java`. I want it to open the file instead.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Post a bigger screenshot please. Which pane is this from?

Comment: Try double clicking?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the **gearing** on the `Project` header

[image]

2. Click on `Autoscroll to Source`

Answer (score 1):

By convention, that menu is doing what it should; it shows you the symbols contained in that class.

If you want to navigate to the file, **don't** rely on your mouse and instead use the keyboard shortcut CTRL+N (or equivalent on Mac) to open a class.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the little settings icon at the top of that project window.
2. Select “Autoscroll to source”

That causes the editor pane for that file (if open) to become the current pane. If it’s not already open, double click.

I always also select “Autoscroll from source” too, so selecting an editor window causes the same file to be selected in the project window